# Multiple actions in a single button/link?

Tags: website-design, forms, buttons, call-to-action, submit

I came across this today while reviewing a mock from a coworker on another project, I told him it was "definitely wrong" but couldn't find any supporting UX guidelines that tackle this exact issue.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1wGrp.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

These were the options below a standard web form to add a user. Aside from the labels being incorrect, the button with TWO actions seems clearly wrong. If you have any best practice/guideline links this conflicts with it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What happens when I 'Save and add another user' and then Cancel? Does the first user persist? Assuming it does (but you never know).

Comment: This is a web form so they are both submit actions, therefore "Save" would submit the form and bring you back to some other page. And "Save And Add Another User" would also submit the form and bring you to the start of the add user process.

Answer (score 2):

This double action button itself can not be a good or bad decision.
Its all about operator's task.

Say you have two situations:

**1. Admin register new emploee in task tracker**

This is something admin doing very rarely (probably) and there is no need to hurry. If you add new user once a year you actually do not care how good the new user form is.
Real life example is JIRA. Its new user form is like it was made by a student.
For such cases there is no need in optimized double ction buttons like *"save, send email and add another"*

[image]

**2. Emploee registers a bunch of attendees for event**

Imagine a queue of 100 people to be registered for event. Operator's UI has to be as lightning fast and optimized as possible. This is where all shortcuts like *"Save and add another"*, *"Save and print badge"*, etc. take place.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The real question is, what happens after a user saves?
If it brings you to a thank you page, then you can add the option to add another user there. Another option could be to have a link above the two buttons that says "Add another user", which would be an expanded field that drops down another form to fill out.

In my opinion, it seems redundant to list "save" on two separate buttons. The primary goal here is to submit the form, so that should be the clear focus.

Furthermore, the option to "save and add.." is a little confusing to me. Will this be submitted and take me to another page? Can I save now and add another user later? I'm just not sure what will happen if I click it.

Try asking your team a few more questions surrounding the "why" and "how" of the purpose and what the focus is.

Answer (score 0):

The positive action should be to the right, the save should, potentially, be changed to 'Save and Exit' and the cancel either gotten rid or kept, depending on how long your user registration process is.

All from experience.

Comment: This is a web form, so the concept of "Exit" seems very odd, even "Save" is incorrect by most web standards. The label should be "Add User" being that's what the button actually does, essentially making the other button "Add User And Add Another User".